# Pyrhon list.remove(x) not working, x not found in list

Tags: python

When I run this code, I am expecting to print 'miller' after printing the list. 'Miller' is shown in the list, please help me understand why the list.remove() does not find 'miller'.

```
guest_list = []
guest_list.append('dostoevsky')
guest_list.append('miller')
guest_list.append('wallace')
guest_list.append('vonnegut')
print(guest_list)

cannot_come = guest_list.remove('miller')
print(cannot_come)
```

['dostoevsky', 'miller', 'wallace', 'vonnegut']
None

Comment: `remove` works in place, it mutates your original list.

Comment: `remove` operates directly on the list and returns None. print `guest_list` and you'll get what you expected

Comment: you can use like this ,,   cannot_come = guest_list.pop()
print(cannot_come)